# Where are my endpoints and what are the AJAX requests doing?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, fiddler, google-developer-tools

I'm testing to see how multiple APIs are performing when run concurrently. My question is that I see on the Developer Tools and Fiddler when the AJAX requests are happening and where they get populated in the UI, so I have an idea of where they're coming from, but I can't find the specific "endpoint" something like "/api/v1/member/{member-number}" to confirm that it is coming from this API call.

I'm not sure if it will necessarily show up on the developer tools or fiddler, but I do have the specific API endpoints given to me for when I tested them as standalone. However, I can't find it to confirm on the UI so that I know I'm hitting the correct point.

I may be over-complicating it by trying to understand what each AJAX request does, and am curious if this is even necessary also? I may just need to follow the network path and see which parameters to correlate, I'm guessing.

Answer (score 0):

Black-box reverse engineering is not something you should be normally doing.

AJAX requests are being triggered by client-side [JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript) so if you want to trace an AJAX call you could use [JavaScript Debugger](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/devtools-user/debugger/) which is available in your [browser developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/Tools_and_setup/What_are_browser_developer_tools)

Be ready to the fact that JavaScript could be [minified](https://minify-js.com/) and additionally [obfuscated](https://obfuscator.io/) so it might be quite hard to read and understand. So I would rather reach out to the application developers and ask them to share/explain the source code.

Given you have [`jmeter`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jmeter) in your tags I would suggest just

1. Recording your requests using [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html)
2. Identify which ones are being executed in parallel
3. Put those under the [Parallel Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/parallel-controller-in-jmeter)

As in order to be able to come up with a proper JMeter script you don't need to understand what each and every request is doing and where does it come from, you need to replicate real browser's network footprint.